# Firebase Exception Not Being Caught

Tags: java, android, exception, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my existing code.

```
mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(registration.getEmail(), registration.getPassword())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(this, authResult -> {
                        Log.i("exception0", "here0");
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(this, exception -> {
                        if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException) {
                            Log.i("exception1", "here");
                        } else if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            Log.i("exception2", "here1");
                        } else if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException) {
                            Log.i("exception3", "here2");
                        } else if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) {
                            Log.i("exception4", "here3");
                        } else if (exception instanceof FirebaseAuthException) {
                            Log.i("exception5", "here4");
                        } else if (exception instanceof FirebaseException) {
                            FirebaseException firebaseException = (FirebaseException) exception;
                            Log.i("exception6", "here5" + firebaseException.getMessage());
                        } else {
                            Log.i("exception7", "here6");
                        }
                    });
```

I know that the exception needs to be a weak password exception but the exception that does get caught is a FirebaseException.

I even tried the following code

```
if(!task.isSuccessful()) {
try {
    throw task.getException();
} catch(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
    mTxtPassword.setError(getString(R.string.error_weak_password));
    mTxtPassword.requestFocus();
} catch(FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
    mTxtEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
    mTxtEmail.requestFocus();
} catch(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException e) {
    mTxtEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_user_exists));
    mTxtEmail.requestFocus();
} catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
}
```

But it would always catch the last generalised exception and not a specific one.

Comment: What do you get if you log `exception.getClass().getName()` in the `here 5` branch?

Answer (score 0):

Attempt this:

```
if(e.getClass().equals(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException.class))
```